# Python- Tkinter, Como utilizo o Photo Image corretamente, nesta situação?

Tags: python, tkinter

A minha dúvida é, como utilizo de forma correta o **label** para mostrar uma imagem no **tkinter**, linguagem **Python**, já que sempre que a janela é aberta, a imagem é exposta, porém totalmente branca, não mostrando o seu conteúdo revelante, tenho esta dúvida, pois o formato da imagem utilizado no código seguinte é **Png**, formato transparente, a imagem está transparente com o conteúdo sólido, mesmo assim, depois de correr o código, aparece apenas como se fosse um **Label** totalmente branco, para mais informações úteis, refiro-me que este código é uma etapa inicial do jogo da forca, a imagem em causa, consta na variável image2, ao qual está acontecendo o erro, a variável image1 não é chamada para o caso, espero atenciosamente, obrigado!!!?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.configure(background="#4F4F4F")
root.option_add('*tearOff', False)


class Game:

    def images(self):
        image1 = PhotoImage(file='Boneco1.png')
        image1 = image1.subsample(1, 3)
        image2 = PhotoImage(file="Bonecolindo.png")
        image2 = image2.subsample(1, 1)
        return [image1, image2]

    def __init__(self):
        root.title("TWG")
        root.geometry("900x700")
        label = ttk.Label(root, text="The Words Game", font=("Times New Roman", 18), background="#4F4F4F", foreground="white")
        label.place(relx=0.5, y=30, anchor="center")
        image = Label(root, image=self.images()[0], borderwidth=2, relief="solid", bg="gray")
        image.place(x=0, rely=0.5, anchor="center")
        imagel = Label(root, image=self.images()[1])
        imagel.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="center")


Game()
root.mainloop()
```

[Esta é a imagem ao qual eu me refiro, ela está transparente em formato **Png**, tem o canal **alpha** correto, utilizei o **GIMP**, aplicativo de edição de imagens, para fazer a transparência, o problema é descrito acima, ao qual se refere, que quando o código é corrido, a imagem aparece totalmente branca...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBlUQ.png)

[A imagem fica em branco como vista na janela, na descrição acima está uma explicação detalhada do que eu já fiz para tentar resolver o problema, pois o código corre, porém sem o que tinha pretendido!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFRAc.png)

Comment: Importante [seguir as instruções dadas da primeira vez que perguntou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/582318/70). Para evitar duplicação de informações o campo de comentários foi desativado nesta postagem aqui, mas você pode restaurar sua postagem original e editar conforme orientado, para que ela seja reavaliada.